# Is "Interlapse" a proper word?

Tags: word-usage

I have heard people use it frequently. This word is not listed in Lexico and Cambridge Dictionary.

The only source I can find online is

> [From the Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Interlapse)
>
> n.    1.  The lapse or interval of time between two events.

What is the equivalent word for this since it is obsolete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interlapse) states that the word "*interlapse*" is ***[obsolete](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/obsolete)*** -

> 1. (*obsolete*) The time between two events.
> 2. (*obsolete*, *rare*) The distance between two things.

Therefore, "*interlapse*" can be considered a word, just that it is not used anymore/rare usage.

This [Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interlapse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinterlapse%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cinterlapse%3B%2Cc0) agrees too -

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! @Justin. I have never thought of checking the wiktionary and Ngram. I added to the original question for equivalent word.

Comment: The current word would be “interval” when speaking of periods of time.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick! I added this new question after @Justin answered my original. That was the answer to the original question so I marked that as an answer. And from this I learned that one question per post is more appropriate and not confusing.  I've upvoted your answer. Sorry for the confusion. Appreciate your answer to this.